# Rewriting Derby DB tables (with FK) via JPA

Tags: jpa, eclipselink

I can fill 2 tables in a DB where the tables have mappings(one table has a FK from he other). The 
EclipseLink DataSource show the flush  to the DB has been done ok. 
I am trying to rewrite the tables (with same data a second time ) while  the persistence.xml  has 
the properties clause as follows : 
  `<property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-create-tables" />`
yet I see no dropping (erase) of the previous tables before the rewriting and therefore get rejected with  the following exception message about  a duplicate key :

> "Internal Exception:
>   java.sql.SQLIntegrityConstraintViolationException: The statement was
>   aborted because it would have caused a duplicate key value in a unique
>   or primary key constraint or unique index identified by
>   'SQL120206135740510' defined on 'HOST'. "  ( HOST is the table pointed
>   to by the FK).

What am I missing in the  persistence.xml   or else that should make the table drop before the rewrite ?
Below see the  persistence.xml   file ( the DB file is called 'test' . The schema is name after the user name (APP in my case) ):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?> 
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd"> 
        <persistence-unit name="jpa_test"> 
                <class>Host</class> 
                <class>Vm</class> 
                <properties> 
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.url" value="jdbc:derby://im6-64s:1527/test;create=true" /> 
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.user" value="APP" /> 
                        <property name="javax.persistence.jdbc.password" value="passw0rd" /> 
                        <!-- EclipseLink should create the database schema automatically --> 
                        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation" value="drop-create-tables" /> 
                        <property name="eclipselink.ddl-generation.output-mode" value="database" /> 
                </properties> 

        </persistence-unit> 
</persistence>
```

Answer (score 1):

"drop-create-tables" should be "drop-and-create-tables"

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the "eclipselink.logging.level" property with a value of Finest or ALL to see why the drop might not be being executed.